# Installation of open km not successful

Tags: windows, server, openkm

OpenKM Installed on
OS: Windows Server 2016
VM: ESX 6.5
After the successful Installation, the Apache Service is not showing in Microsoft Services Console (MSC).

Find below the error generated after a login attempt :

http://192.168.0.28:8080/OpenKM/login.jsp
Application error
Class:  org.apache.jasper.JasperException
Message:    An exception occurred processing JSP page [/login_desktop.jsp] at line [230] 227:
Date:   Wed Jul 22 15:59:10 PKT 2020
Regards,
Anwar